# Heatmaps layer on OSMdroid mapview

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-mapview, osmdroid

Is it possible to display a Google Maps heatmap layer like this https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-heatmap as a layer onto a custom OSMdroid Mapview?

Or is there a simple way to directly plot the heatmap-geopoints [{lat, lon, weight-value},..] as a layer onto the map?

Comment: Did you find a good solution for rendering a heat map on a OSMdroid Mapview?

Answer (score 0):

I found this nice Python Script by Seth Golub
https://github.com/sethoscope/heatmap/blob/master/heatmap.py
that converts a list of lat, lon [weight] values or a .gpx into a heatmap - with nice customizing options.

On top of that there is a Andrew Harvey's wrapper for rendering tiles from your file
https://github.com/andrewharvey/OpenStreetMap-User-Edits-Heatmap/blob/master/render-heatmap-to-tiles.pl

My first tests have shown that I am able to create similar results as on Google Maps with these scripts.